# Redirect to "You Are Forbidden" page without changing URL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, permissions

I set up a custom Authorization Attribute in my project to do some checks on a user's permissions. If they aren't allowed to do a certain activity, they get redirected to a "You Are Forbidden" page via `RedirectToRouteResult`. However, I would like to make this function without changing the URL so the user can refresh the page if they receive permission. Is this possible?

How I'm doing it currently. It sends to the URL `Forbidden/`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthActivityAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId = 0;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!ViewIsAuthorizedActivity(ActivityName))
        {
            filterContext.Result = Forbid();
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult Forbid()
    {
        return new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller", "Home" },
                    { "action", "Forbidden" },
                    { "Activity", ActivityId },
                    { "area", ""}
                });
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

Edit / Solution:

I ended up using a combination of rendering `PartialView` for GET Requests and `RedirectToRouteResult` for POST Requests. I chose this for two reasons:

1. The user has the page loaded before losing permission, therefore the Forbidden partial view isn't loaded.  Without the `RedirectToRouteResult` on POSTs, they could POST even though they don't have permission.
2. Someone could attempt to over post the page and have some success if they hit some Included values.

Attribute:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!ViewIsAuthorizedActivity(ActivityName))
    {
        string requestMethod = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (requestMethod == "GET")
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Authorization = "FORBIDDEN";
        }
        else if (requestMethod == "POST")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller", "Foo" },
                    { "action", "Bar" },
                    { "area", ""}
                });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Authorization == "FORBIDDEN")
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Forbidden!";
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Forbidden.cshtml");
}
else
{
    <!-- Page -->
}
```

Comment: instead of redirecting, perhaps you could load a partial depending on site size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a partial is the way to go.  Add a partial to your page that looks like this:

```
@if(ViewData["FORBIDDEN"] == true)
{

<div id="forbidden">

<div/>
}
else{
rest of page here
}
```

in your action check for permission and set the ViewData["FORBIDDEN"] based on it

Comment: Did consider the partial, but was wondering if there was another way in the structure I have.  Doing this, I would need to have two different authorization attributes... one that sends some ViewData to the ``filterContext.Controller.ViewBag`` and one that actually doesn't let you touch the controller.  I did it this way initially to prevent someone from POSTing to the page without permission.  I believe if there was a partial view but the same URL, someone could sneak in a POST to that URL 
still, correct? So I think I'd have one on POSTs and one on GETs... if that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, I think I will just change my Attribute to handle two different request types... GET / POST... doing two different things.  Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Yeah I decorating the action with [HttpGet] should prevent posts to it.